# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /ultimate.twitter.feed.php

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am getting this error on a server but the same thing works fine on my local machine.

Here is the lines of code which causes the error on the server

```
private function formattedTweet($tweet) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/{tweet:([a-z-:0-9_]+)}/i', function($match) use($tweet) {

        $dimensions = explode(':', $match[1]);

        if(!isset($tweet[$dimensions[0]]))
            return $match[0];

        $replacement = $tweet[$dimensions[0]];

        for($i = 1; $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
            if(!isset($replacement[$dimensions[$i]]))
                return $match[0];
            else
                $replacement = $replacement[$dimensions[$i]];
        }

        return is_array($replacement) ? $match[0] : $replacement;

    }, self::option('format' . ($tweet['is_retweet'] ? '_retweet' : '')));
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Does the error give a line number?

Comment: and also can you write this error ?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP versions are the same locally and on the server?

Comment: where did you define that function in a class or it just a function?

Comment: Here is the Error -- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in line No.149

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you are trying to run this on a PHP version older than 5.3, which does not support the anonymous function of `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Can you upgrade to PHP 5.3? Otherwise, you'll need to rewrite the anonymous method as class method, passing the `$tweet` variable as object property instead of closure, and use a regular `array($this, 'callbackMethod')` as the callback.